# How to write the following pattern mathematically?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\begin{array}{c|l} 
n & k \\
\hline
4&6\\
5&9\\
6&\frac{25}{2} \\
7&\frac{33}{2} \\
8&21 \\
9&26 \\
10&\frac{63}{2} \\
11& \frac{75}{2}
\end{array}$$

I observed the following pattern.
$$\underbrace{6 \to 9}_{3} \underbrace{\to \frac{25}{2}}_{\frac{7}{2}} \underbrace{\to \frac{33}{2}}_{4} \underbrace{\to 21}_{\frac{9}{2}} \underbrace{\to 26}_{5} \underbrace{\to \frac{63}{2}}_{\frac{11}{2}} \underbrace{\to \frac{75}{2}}_{6}$$

Then the difference between two consecutive resulting numbers is $\frac{1}{2}$.

How to write the relation between $n$ & $k$?

Comment: Where is this pattern coming from?  Are you just given a bunch of terms?

Comment: I found a pattern in this number set. I just

Comment: You can interpolate them with a function which has a derivative which integrates to a linear function. Which functions have a linear derivative?

Comment: You've noticed that the second differences are constant, and so you should be looking for a quadratic equation.

Comment: Hint: Write the integer differences as halves of integers and you'll see a clearer pattern. Then Use @Joppy 's observation to find a quadratic expression for $k$ as a function of $n$.

Comment: Thank you! I got the recursive formula!

Comment: Why did you remove text from your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Since the successive differences $\Delta k = k(n + 1) - k(n)$ are linear, $k$ is given by a quadratic expression in $n$.

Alternatively, one can modify appropriately the usual identity $$\sum_{i = 1}^m i = \frac{1}{2} m (m + 1)$$ to produce an expression for the partial sum of any arithmetic sequence.

---

In response to a comment, here's how one can apply the second hint:

The observed pattern says that $k(4) = 6$ and that the value $k(n)$ is given by adding to $k(4) = 6$ the $n - 4$ half-integers starting with $3$:

$$k(n) = 6 + \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 4} \left(3 + \frac{i - 1}{2}\right) .$$

Notice that if one only wants *some* explicit expression for $k(n)$, this above certainly suffices. It works for $n = 4$, too, taking the usual convention that an empty sum has value zero. Now, if one wants a closed-form expression for this quantity, we can manipulate this sum so that we can take advantage of the above formula for the sum of the first $m$ integers:
$$
\begin{align*}
k(n)
&= 6 + \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 4} \left(\frac{5}{2} + \frac{i}{2}\right) \\
&= 6 + \frac{5}{2} (n - 4) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 4} i \\
&= -4 + \frac{5}{2} n + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 4} i .
\end{align*}
$$
Taking $m = n - 4$ in the sum formula and substituting gives
$$k(n) = -4 + \frac{5}{2} n + \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{1}{2} (n - 4)[(n - 4) + 1]\right] = \frac{1}{4} n^2 + \frac{3}{4} n - 1.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for answering !

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: By using the recursive formula I could obtained the sequence. But I didn't understand the relation of the partial sum.

Comment: @Oily I've added some details about how one can use that formula for the partial sum to produce a closed-form formula for $k(n)$.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it was useful.

Comment: Yes. It was the exact idea that I needed to know. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

It is a sequence, right? You can define it recuresively as:

$a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1.5$ and
$a_{n+1} = a_n + (a_n-a_{n-1}) + \frac{1}{2}$ for $n\geq 1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**$$g(k) = \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \partial x$$

where $g$ is the function you enumerate and the integral is your observation.